# How to scrape content from the simpleXML_Element_Object?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, scrape

I am trying to scrape the contents from the Information Box of wikipedia on the right hand side of any wikipage.

I am using DOMXpath to scrape the contents.

On [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google) link's Information box(on the right hand side), I am trying to scrape the `Traded as` section. However in the page source it is formed of multiple href's.

```
Traded as:  NASDAQ: GOOG
            NASDAQ-100 Component
            S&P 500 Component
```

And My SIMPLE_XML_Element_Object looks like this

```
SimpleXMLElement object {
 @attributes => array(1) (
[class] => (string)
)
 th => SimpleXMLElement object {
@attributes => array(2) (
  [scope] => (string) row
  [style] => (string) text-align:left;
)
a => (string) Traded as
}
td => SimpleXMLElement object {
@attributes => array(2) (
  [class] => (string)
  [style] => (string)
)
a => array(4) (
  [0] => (string) NASDAQ
  [1] => (string) GOOG
  [2] => (string) NASDAQ-100 Component
  [3] => (string) S&P 500 Component
)
}
```

and this is what I have tried to scrape the contents.

```
foreach ($xmlElements->xpath("//div[@id='mw-content-text']/table[@class='infobox vcard']/tr") as $node) 
{
   $name = (string)$node->th;
   if(empty($name))
     $name = (string)$node->th->a;
   if(is_array($node->td->a))
       $value = implode('~', (string) $node->td->a);
    else
       $value = (string) $node->td->a;
}
```

However I am not able to get the value formed as `"NASDAQ: GOOD ~ NASDAQ-100 Component ~ NASDAQ-100 Component"` and I am the getting the value as `"NASDAQ"` alone, that is not the required one.

How to get the value from the node if it is an array?

Hope I am clear with my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_user1518659.php

Outputs: string(64) "NASDAQ: GOOG ~ NASDAQ-100 Component ~ S&P 500 Component"

This is really much easier to get right if you just use native PHP functions!

```
<?php // RAY_temp_user1518659.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

// ACQUIRE THE DOCUMENT
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google';
$htm = file_get_contents($url);

// ACTIVATE THIS TO SEE THE ENTIRE DOCUMENT
// echo htmlentities($htm);

// ISOLATE THE "TRADED AS" PART
$sig = 'Traded as';
$arr = explode($sig, $htm);
$htm = $arr[1];
$sig = '</tr>';
$arr = explode($sig, $htm);
$htm = $arr[0];

// REFORMAT THE DATA INTO A TILDE-SEPARATED STRING
$new = trim(strip_tags($htm));
$new = explode(PHP_EOL, $new);
$new = implode(' ~ ', $new);

// SHOW THE WORK PRODUCT
var_dump($new);
```

Best regards, ~Ray

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would be much more delighted if I ll be able to get the answer following my code procedure(The one I used in the question). Also let me know where I have done wrong.

Comment: Also I would like to parse node by node. Dont want to parse the whole HTML each time.

Comment: I cannot begin to figure out what your code might be doing wrong because SimpleXML hides some of the required information from var_dump().  DOMXpath is just not the right tool for the job.  And there is no "node-by-node advantage -- the entire document must be read no matter how you try to parse it.  About the best I can do for you is post a tested-and-working code example, and I have done that.  FWIW it was tested with other corporate pages and it always came back with a sensible response.  Try changing "Google" to "IBM" in the $url variable and you'll see how it works.

Comment: please check it. It doesn't seem to give '~' separated output. Just giving output without any separation.

Comment: Please check what?  I see the tilde here: http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_user1518659.php

Comment: Also I want to write the result in the file. It is printing along with "&#160;". i.e." US$ 72.574&#160;billion (2011)[3]". How to remove that?

Comment: I do not see that in my example.  If you want to write a string to a file, you can use PHP file_put_contents() function.  If you're new to PHP and want to get a foundation in the language, this is a reasonably good place to start: http://www.sitepoint.com/books/phpmysql5/

Comment: what is purpose of echoing <pre> tag at top.

Comment: The PRE tag makes the output easy to read when you use var_dump() or print_r().  I use those functions a lot when I'm writing code.

Comment: But this is the output I get when I run your code. "<pre>string(60) "NASDAQ:&#160;GOOG
NASDAQ-100 Component
S&amp;P 500 Component"" I think PHP_EOL is not getting executed. where I am missing?

Comment: You are seeing the output of the var_dump($new) instruction -- the last line of the script.  You might try using echo $new instead.  I don't really care about what you do with the string -- I am only able to show you how to isolate the data.

Comment: I simply want to write the string into a file as '~' separted. But your code on my computer shows the output I ve given in the above comment. I think PHP_EOL doesn't seems to work for me. because on my machine explode(PHP_EOL, $new) gives oly array of 1 value(i.e. with index '0' alone) that is where it is getting wrong.

Comment: Try using var_dump($new) right after this instruction: $new = trim(strip_tags($htm));  If your PHP installation is correctly configured, PHP_EOL should be the end of line character.  It can mean \n, \r, or \r\n depending on your OS, and it is context aware.  You can try substituting one of those control character(s) to see if the explode() works correctly.  When you find one, then use that.

Comment: I used "\n" instead of PHP_EOL and it is working fine. thanks.

Comment: lets say in another case I want to get the 'website' name from wikipedia. e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americom .  here the website name just shows the company name. In this case I want to take the underlying URL(i.e. href value). How to handle such cases?

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/ -- There are many links on the wikipedia page for Americom.  What information do you want to acquire?

Comment: $sig = 'Website' and $url = 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americom' on your code just gives 'SES Americom' as result. But I want the URL beneath it. i.e. 'http://www.ses-worldskies.com/worldskies/'

Comment: How would you go about isolating that URL?  What would the signal strings be?

Comment: At this point, in respect of your time, I'm going to step back from the question and recommend that you hire a professional developer.  You will get the results you need much faster!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried outputting the array as print_f($value) to see whether it has the data you need? If all the stocks have the same pattern and you implode them with "~", I believe the first element of array will contain ""NASDAQ: GOOD", the second "NASDAQ-100 Component", so by outputting the second element of the array you will get the needed data.

Comment: I have tried var_dump ing it and it shows oly "NASDAQ" and I am unable to get all the values. I am missing somewhere in my code. please see the page source and try to find it.

Comment: You get NASDAQ as the first "a" of the td, try to foreach $node->td->a as foreach($node->td->a as $subnode)

Comment: the better thing would be if it is an array I can use foreach otherwise just print it.